# Pyodbc on El Capitan

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm having trouble installing pyodbc on El Capitan. I have another virtualenv which was created during Yosemite days that has pyodbc.

I am installing pyodbc through the following command:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include" --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

It errs out saying it cannot find odbc dynamic library.

ld: library not found for -lodbc

The version of python I'm using is python 2.7.10(but has similar problems installing in python 2.6.9 too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add /usr/local/lib to compiler dynamic library path

pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include" **--global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"** --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc

Comment: This answer was the solution that finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc now supplies binary wheels for macOS, for Python 2.7 and 3.4+, so no compilation is necessary.  Note that these are built with unixODBC, not iODBC, however.